# Google Apps Calendar theme

Tags: google-calendar

I can easily change my Google Apps email theme to match my company's colors.

Is there a way that I can accomplish the same thing for the calendar?

I looked in all the settings and so on, but can't seem to find anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This might be because the calendars themselves use color-coding. More likely it's just been overlooked.

You can use an image as the background for your calendar. There's no reason you couldn't, say, use a large version of your company logo.